Issue with loading CSS files in Vite
I have a React app that I am migrating from Webpack4 to Vite.
There is a problem with loading CSS from the .jsx files, I get the following error:
 "src/reactFile.jsx:7:19": ERROR: Cannot import "src/someFile.css" into a JavaScript file without an output path configured

I don't really understand why this is or how to fix it.
In the jsx file, the CSS import looks like:
 import './renderCount.css';

I've tried multiple updates to vite.config.js based on answers to vaguely similar questions, chatGPT, etc.
Any advice?
